# Import tkinter fails in ubuntu on python 3.6

Tags: 17.10, python3, tkinter

The python 2 install on my ubuntu 17.10 install works fine, Tkinter is imported without errors, but on the python 3 install, import tkinter fails.

I've tried to reinstall python3-tk and reinstall python3 altogether.

The OS is ubuntu 17.10 with the default GNOME desktop environment, and the python 3 version is python 3.6.3.

I'm out of ideas on how to fix this. A lot of my projects rely on tkinter for the interface, and I can't make it work.

Comment: How are you exactly importing the module?

Comment: In the python3 console, `import tkinter as tk`